# Как убрать обтекание текстом картинки при добавлении ее через :before

Tags: html, css

Есть n-количество строк <р>, перед каждой вставлена картинка через :before, текст обтекает картинку. Подскажите как можно убрать обтекание?

```
.jumbotron.content-faq p.img-cont{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.4;
padding-left: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.jumbotron.content-faq p.img-cont:before {
content: '';
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
background: url('./img/check.png') no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 2px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: float: left - удалить

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/udh6pdkr/

Comment: пробовал, при удалении float,  картинка вообще пропадает

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо, добавил position:absolute, все получилось))

Comment: ну вот используйте какие-нибудь другие методы для позиционирования картинки, кроме `float`: например, `position` и `left`